# Upload image from iOS to PHP script

Tags: php, objective-c, ios, image-uploading

I've had a quick Google around for this but has anyone got any resources or tutorials for doing this?

I'd like to give the user the option of taking a picture with their camera or choosing one from the library and upload it to a PHP script which would save it in a folder...I can do the PHP part, but not sure about the Objective-C iOS bit...

Comment: have you succeeded in uploading a file from iOS to PHP ?

Comment: @danipralea To be honest I have abandoned iOS app dev for the time being!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use#sending_a_form_post_with_ASIFormDataRequest) on the iOS device, and then google up how to receive uploaded files in PHP. It's fairly simple--data about the file will show up in a $_FILES associative array, there's a function to move the file from the temp directory that it starts out in into your own directories.

Comment: This. ASIHTTPRequest has a class called ASIFormDataRequest (or something similar) that will handle this no problem.

Answer (score 1):

NSData *data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(yourUIImage);

Post the data to php as you would normally.

Answer (score -5):

Have a look at [PicUp](http://www.iosnoops.com/appinfo/picup-for-iphone/354101378) ([App Store link](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/picup/id354101378?mt=8&ign-mpt=uo=2)). I've not personally used it but looks easy enough.

Comment: How does this help? I need to code it, not get an app to do it!

Comment: This helps by letting you use file uploads in a web page. I assumed this would be okay as you'd tagged it php. Next time just limit your tags to objective-c if that's the only solution you're after huh?